# Creating a form based PHP application from scratch

Tags: php, mysql

I am interning for a company that manufactures parts and has to run a number of tests for chromaticity, brightness, contrast, ect. Currently, they are using MS Access as a front-end to input their data, which is then printed out as a report when they are finished.  The data is not stored anywhere.  Also, for some reason they have also created these "data forms" using excel which also do not store the data anywhere.  It is my job to find a solution that will allow them to store all of their data in a mySQL database for later use, however, since they are using multiple UIs to input the data, I am unsure what to do. I have already come to an agreement with my superiors that they need to merge into a single UI, so...

Here are my options:

1) Attempt to link their already functional MS Access UI to my mySQL database (which could be a horrendous failure since I know nothing of Access), and convert all excel forms to Access forms

2) Convert their Access forms into Excel forms and then have to deal with capturing data from excel which is an extremely tedious coding job since there are about 50+ cells I need to capture in each of there hundreds of documents.

3) Create a PHP application that will allow an administrator to add attributes and define fields which will create a form and corresponding mySQL table for that form.  Basically, taking the capabilities of the Access form builder/ forms and putting them into a web application.  Would this take very long to do so from scratch?

Sorry, this was long, but I am the only one with programming background here and am just an intern, haha, so I need some advice.

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Approach number 3 could be done quickly with [Symphony CMS](http://symphony-cms.com/). You would create a [section](http://symphony-cms.com/learn/concepts/view/sections/) for each form, and then you (or an admin) would add fields to that section using Symphony's GUI section editor. The form would then be available in the CMS, and ready for adding entries with.

Symphony CMS is very flexible, and you could generate reports (HTML or other formats) using it. It also has a [RESTful API](http://symphonyextensions.com/extensions/rest_api/).

There'a also a [CSV importing extension](http://symphonyextensions.com/extensions/importcsv/), which might be good for your Excel data.

Comment: I was curious if there was some kind of already created framework for this type of thing. Thanks for the help, I will look into it

Comment: Cool. The people at the forum are very helpful, and most are more knowledgeable than I. http://symphony-cms.com/discuss/